# How can I convert Inline CSS code into External File CSS Code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. After writing every post, I will insert some comments manually while posting the article and it needs to look like the below image. I have the inline CSS for it but how to convert it into external CSS code and specific it in the webpage?
[image]

I need to remove the space on the left side and also need the comments to be more closer to save space.

My Inline CSS code:-

```css
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<hr style="background: 0px center rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-top-width: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;" />
<div class="comment authorComment" id="comment8167199" style="background-color: #fffce5; clear: both; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 40px; position: relative; word-wrap: break-word;">
<div class="author_photo" style="float: left; height: 25px; left: 8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 8px; width: 25px;">
</div>
<div class="comment_meta" style="color: #888888; font-size: 0.857em; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 0.8em !important; padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;">
<strong style="color: #333333;">anonymous&nbsp;</strong><span class="timestamp" style="display: inline-block;"><small style="background-color: #8b9a18; border-radius: 3px; color: white; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 2px 5px; position: absolute; right: 8px; top: 8px;">Comment</small></span></div>
<div class="comment_body" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;">
<div class="" style="margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 0px;">
[<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;">Here I enter command manually everytime</span><span style="font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;">]</span></div>
</div>
</div>
<hr style="background: 0px center rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-top-width: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;" />
<div class="comment" id="comment8167751" style="background-color: white; margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 40px; position: relative; word-wrap: break-word;">
<div class="author_photo" style="color: #333333; float: left; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; height: 25px; left: 8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 8px; width: 25px;">
</div>
<div class="comment_meta" style="margin-bottom: 0.8em; padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;">
<span style="color: #333333; font-family: &quot;arial&quot; , &quot;helvetica&quot; , sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 11.8266px; line-height: 15.3746px;"><b>anonymous</b></span></span></div>
<div class="comment_body" style="color: #333333; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;">
<div class="" style="margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 0px;">
[Here I enter command manually everytime]</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr style="background: 0px center rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-top-width: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;" />
<div class="comment authorComment" id="comment8169379" style="background-color: #fffce5; clear: both; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 40px; position: relative; word-wrap: break-word;">
<div class="author_photo" style="float: left; height: 25px; left: 8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 8px; width: 25px;">
</div>
<div class="comment_meta" style="color: #888888; font-size: 0.857em; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 0.8em !important; padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;">
<strong style="color: #333333;">anonymous</strong><span class="timestamp" style="display: inline-block;"><small style="background-color: #8b9a18; border-radius: 3px; color: white; font-size: 0.9em; padding: 2px 5px; position: absolute; right: 8px; top: 8px;"><span style="font-size: 10.6439px; line-height: 13.8371px;">Comment</span></small></span></div>
<div class="comment_body" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;">
<div class="" style="margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 0px;">
[<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;">Here I enter command manually everytime</span><span style="font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;">]</span></div>
</div>
</div>
<hr style="background: 0px center rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-top-width: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;" />
<div class="comment" id="comment8173614" style="background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 40px; position: relative; word-wrap: break-word;">
<div class="author_photo" style="float: left; height: 25px; left: 8px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 8px; width: 25px;">
</div>
<div class="comment_meta" style="color: #888888; font-size: 0.857em; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 0.8em !important; padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;">
<b style="color: #333333; font-size: 11.8266px; line-height: 15.3746px;">anonymous</b></div>
<div class="comment_body" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;">
<div class="" style="margin-bottom: 1em; padding: 0px;">
[Here I enter command manually everytime]</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr style="background: 0px center rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-top-width: 0px; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px;" />
<div class="comment" id="comment8174843" style="background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13.8px; line-height: 20.7px; margin: 0.5em 0px 0px; min-height: 40px; padding: 8px 0px 0px 40px; position: relative; word-wrap: break-word;">
<br /></div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```css
dhr {
             background: 0px center #ffffff       /* This type of heading MUST be Green and Large! */
             border-bottom-color: #cccccc
             border-bottom-style: dotted 
             border-bottom-width: 2px
             border-top-width: 0px
             color: #333333
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
             font-size: 13.8px
             line-height: 20.7px }
```

In the HTML Page:

```css
<hr class="dhr" />

<span class="dhr">[Here I enter command manually everytime]</span>
```

It isn't working. Can anyone please provide the the external CSS code and the Page code? If possible remove the left side code and gap between comments. My external CSS file name is **custom.css**. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The did not work, as every class name needs to have a `.` (dot) before the class name like `.dhr` when placed in external CSS

Comment: Can you please provide me the code

Answer (score 1):

`dhr` is a [type selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors). It selects `<dhr>` elements (which [don't exist in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1)).

Your element is a member of the *class* `dhr` so you need a [class selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html): `.dhr`

---

After you fix that, you need to correct the rules in your ruleset. They must be separated by semicolons, exactly as you did when you wrote them inline in a style attribute. (This is an error that a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) would have picked up).

Comment: @user3042646 — I did. I told you exactly which piece of code was wrong and how you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.dhr` rather than just `dhr` in your CSS.

Reason: `.dhr` represents a class(`<element class='dhr'>`) whereas just `dhr` represents an element(`<dhr>`).

So use this:

```
.dhr {
             background: 0px center #ffffff       /* This type of heading MUST be Green and Large! */
             border-bottom-color: #cccccc
             border-bottom-style: dotted 
             border-bottom-width: 2px
             border-top-width: 0px
             color: #333333
             font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
             font-size: 13.8px
             line-height: 20.7px }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added the 'dot' like the above on my custom.css file. So now what code I should enter on the html page to display the CSS content.